# Help with finding the type of output for a mems mircophone

Tags: datasheet, microphone, homework, medical, mems-microphone

I am using [this MEMS microphone](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/gmems-technologies/GTM2718AB381XPR1/14311310) for a stethoscope project. The data sheet recommends the following interface circuit.

I can't seem to find where it states specifically that it is a differential output instead of a single-ended one. Am I right in understanding it as outputting a differential output?

[image]

Comment: The mic (the piece of hardware) is only the circle with mic. Rest is hardware outside the component. Like the recommended one.

Comment: Do you intend to use an analog one? Or a digital?

Comment: Is there both, I am under the impression that the mic only output analog. I plan to feed it into a analog filter.

Comment: Feeding straight into a differential opamp from capacitors is asking for trouble. There needs to be biasing and feedback. So, the diagram is illustrative only

Comment: Hi again, I am glad you found an analog-output MEMS mic but the Chinese manufacturer does not know the details of an opamp. The other website with your heartbeat project was down.

Answer (score 1):

It is a single ended output, see just one "OUT" pin, even if they don't explicitly say so.  If it were a differential output, there would be an "OUT+" and an "OUT-" pin.

What they have shown is their recommended way to connect to a differential-input amplifier, and to be honest I'm not completely happy with how they show that (there seem to be a lot of unstated assumptions).

I am surprised they didn't show, instead or as well, a simpler recommended connection to a single-ended-input amplifier... like a series DC blocking capacitor going to a the input of an amplifier, pulled to (the amp's) mid-rail by a high value resistor.  Signal ground would be shared between the MEMS and the amplifier.